# Trivialization of the orthonormal frame bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds, fiber-bundles

Given an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ with Riemannian metric $\eta$, the orthonormal frame bundle over $M$ is defined as the set of all orthonormal frames over all points in $M$. Denote such bundle by $O(M)$.

---

**Claim:** It is a trivial bundle over $M$

"*Proof*": For every $x \in M$, fix an orthonormal basis for $T_xM$. Let $\phi: O(M) \to O(n, \mathbb{R})\times M$ be defined by $\phi(r_x) = (A_{r_x}, x)$, where $A_{r_x}$ is the matrix whose columns are $X_1, ..., X_n$, where $r_x = (X_1, ..., X_n)$ and the coordinates are written with respect to the fixed basis.

Now, if we define $\theta: O(n, \mathbb{R})\times M \to O(M)$ by $\theta(A, x) = (r_x)$, where $r_x = (A_1, ..., A_n)$, the columns of $A$, in the tangent space $T_xM$, we get that $\theta$ and $\phi$ are inverses of each other.

Thus, $O(M)$ inherits a manifold structure via the bijection $\phi$ and, therefore, this mapping becomes a diffeomorphism. $\square$

---

**Question**: What is wrong with the above proof? I'm not very good with geometry, and I can't see the flaw in the reasoning...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Given @Didier's comment, my suspicions were indeed correct and the above isn't a trivialization. In that case, what is the topology on $O(M)$ that makes it a manifold?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for a continuous frame to exist on $M$ (in fact this is equivalent to having a trivial tangent bundle), so the map $x\mapsto$ "the reference fixed basis of $T_xM$" has no reason to be continuous. Thus, your "trivialization" isn't one.

Comment: You seem to know/suspect the proof is not correct. Can you please say why? Is this the solution to an exercise which was not accepted? (Your question is lacking context)

Comment: @Thomas Honestly, it's a hunch based on the fact that I couldn't find this information anywhere, and I feel it would have been proven somewhere were it true

Comment: Presumably you know the hairy ball theorem: There is no nowhere-vanishing vector field on $S^2$. For surfaces, having a trivial frame bundle is equivalent to having a nowhere-zero vector field. However, it's worth asking a more advanced question: Can you find an example of a manifold with a nowhere-zero vector field but still a non-trivial tangent bundle (hence non-trivial frame bundle)?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid proof of the statement "If there is a global choice of basis, then then $O(M)$ is trivial".  The problem is that on most manifolds one cannot find such a global basis.

Comment: @Gauss Regarding your edit: **local** frames always exist so your construction works **locally** and this gives you **local** trivializations. The topology should be obvious then. But it is even more easier to consider these frame bundles as subspaces of $TM\oplus \cdots \oplus TM$, and the topology is the induced topology

Comment: @Didier I understand your proposal - my problem is, currently, "pasting together" the topologies obtained locally in such a way that the topology obtained globally is still Hausdorff

Comment: For two frames: either they don't have the same basepoint and in that case, there are two disjoint local trivializations separating them. Or either they have the same basepoint, and this reduces to show that $O(n)$ is Hausdorff.